# Weird graph in Linear regression using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am plotting a Linear Regression model using pyplot. Below is my code.

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color ='red')
plt.show()
```

When I plot using the above code, the plot is as shown below:
[image: Scatter Plot]

I then plotted the line graph using the code below:

```
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

It shows a line as expected.
[image: Line Grpah]

But when I try to plot both of them together, the graph is getting messed up as shown below:

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color ='red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: Linear Regression]

Please let me know if I have to do any extra coding to plot a Linear regression graph properly.

Answer (score 2):

Pyplot connects the dots between points in the order of their occurrence in `X_train`, but there's usually nothing known about the ordering of that. It's rarely sorted. You're going to need to sort your array before plotting it.

```
sorted_indices = numpy.argsort(X_train)
sorted_X = X_train[sorted_indices]
plt.plot(sorted_X, regressor.predict(sorted_X), color = 'blue')
```

Comment: Admittedly your case does look pretty weird, but it may be some quirk of matplotlib. I'm not sure this is going to help.